# Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I want to list a company name in the `author` field of a bibliographic entry:

```
@book{CUDA,
  author    = {NVIDIA Corporation},
  title     = {NVIDIA CUDA Compute Unified Device Architecture Programming Guide},
  publisher = {NVIDIA Corporation},
  year      = {2007}
}
```

But the entry keeps showing up "N. Corporation".  Is there a way to get the full author name to show up?  I'm currently using the `siam` BibTEX style.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Just enclose the the author field in another set of braces:

```
@book{CUDA, 
   author = {{NVIDIA Corporation}}, 
   title = {NVIDIA CUDA Compute Unified Device Architecture Programming Guide}, 
   publisher = {NVIDIA Corporation}, 
   year = {2007}
}
```

Comment: Enclosing in braces will also make BibTeX obey the capitalization.

Comment: @Kit - Making BibTeX obey capitalization by enclosing the material in an extra pair of curly braces is mainly of relevance for the `title` field. To the best of my knowledge, no BibTeX style messes with the capitalization of names in the `author` and `editor` fields.

Comment: Does not work well if you are using alphanumeric ordering for the references. A reference with author in double curly brackets will be listed at the very end of the bibliography. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: @koo Using the `alpha` bibliography style either with or without `natbib` sorts things correctly.  So there's probably something else going on. If you can reproduce the problem with a minimal document you can ask a new question.  See [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) for how to make the example.

Comment: When working with the IEEE style, the double braces alone did not work for me. Adding a backslash did the trick:`@book{CUDA, 
       author = {\{NVIDIA Corporation}}, 
       title = {NVIDIA CUDA Compute Unified Device Architecture Programming Guide}, 
       publisher = {NVIDIA Corporation}, 
       year = {2007}
    }`

Comment: Double braces around the complete name, not just the all-caps part.  (I needed it for `{{SRI Corporation}}`.)