# Changing author name in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have to include a technical document in my citations. The document doesn't have a specific author, but is rather published by an Institute. The sample bibtex entry is given below:

```
@manual{river2009,
author = {Alternate Hydo Energy Centre},
institution = {Some Institute},
 month = {August},
 organization = {Some Organization},
 publisher = {Some Directorate Ministry, Some Government},
 title = {{Status Paper On Environment}},
year = {2009}
}
```

When I compile the document the author entry is automatically changed to following:

```
@manual{river2009,
author = {Energy, Centre Alternate Hydro},
institution = {Some Insitute},
month = {August},
organization = {Some Organization},
publisher = {Some Directorate Ministry, Some Government},
title = {{Status Paper On Environment}},
year = {2009}

}
```

And in the final citation the entry comes under the name of *Energy, C. A. H* instead of *Alternate Hydo Energy Centre*. Is there anyway in which I can preserve the author name as it is, without the entry being juxtaposed and abbreviated?

I am using  `\bibliographystyle{kluwer}` .

Comment: You need to put the name in an extra set of braces.

Comment: Looks like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/getting-bibtex-to-spell-out-the-first-name to me (that one could do with a better title!)

Comment: What programs are you using?  Compiling with `latex` and `bibtex` will not alter the contents of the `bib` file.  In general the solution to get this type of author correctly printed is to enclose in an extra set of brackets: `{{Alternate Hydo Energy Centre}}`.  There must be a duplicate question around somewhere...

Comment: I am compiling using `xelatex`. When I use the double brackets as suggested I get _Energy, Centre Alternate Hydro_ . The abbreviations have gone, but the order of the words is still changed.