# Override firstinits=true for some entries in bib

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I have a bib entry that is just a forum name and the URL. The problem is that all the bibliography is generated using firstinits=true. For this one with firstinits=true biblatex shortens the company name.

Any idea?

```
 @misc{UPNP,
   author =       {{UP}n{P} {F}orum},
   url =          {http://www.upnp.org},
   urldate =      2014,
 }
```

[For] U. Forum. Url: http://www.upnp.org

If I left the author blank and put the content in organization/institution then the cite is only the year (BTW I'm using alphabetic IEEE).

Comment: does it work, if you put all in second brackets: {{UPnP Forum}}?

Comment: Great... seems so. I'm quite new with bib so this is why I'm asking such "stupid" stuff. Thanks a lot. So for overriding anything the best is to put double brackets?

Comment: With double brackets your string will remain unmodified (in the very most cases). I think it has to do with macro expansion, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @musicman - It's not related to macro expansion, which would be a TeX-side activity. Encasing the contents of the author field in double braces instructs BibTeX (a program that's separate from (La)TeX) *not* to parse it to find first names, von parts, surnames, etc., and instead to treat the contents of the field as a literal string. This is useful when dealing with "corporate authors", such as `{{UPnP Forum}}`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Mico. Same with biber of course.

Comment: @Mico Using this way for coorporate authors I'm struggling when putting them in bold as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187994/multiple-names-bold-in-bibliography . Any idea?

Comment: Although the title is not really, this question body is clearly a duplicate of [Using a 'corporate author' in the “author” field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864).