# Multiple names bold in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bold, bibentry

I'm following the guidelines from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160132/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex-without-consistent-author-formatting). However I'm struggling when trying to put in bold another name besides mine. The main characteristic is that the entry is like:

```
@TECHREPORT{EntryDeliverable,
  author = {{Company 1 name} and {Company 2 name}},
  title = {{Title}},
}
```

Note: Include the company name {} because I don't want the company name to be shortened when using firstinits=true.

When I read the bbl file for Company 1 name I get:

```
{{hash=aaf4dfbf2d0b73914eae5cf63523f601}{{Company\bibnamedelimb 1\bibnamedelimb name}}{C\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}{}{}}
```

Note: name modified, so hash is not working.

Then, I have tried with all the options as below

```
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
 {{{Company\bibnamedelimb 1\bibnamedelimb name}}, %
  {{Company\bibnamedelimb 1\bibnamedelimb name}, }, %
  {, {Company\bibnamedelimb 1\bibnamedelimb name}, }, %
 }
```

What is the correct form to do it.

BTW, how can I do it with the hash option.

Comment: Please post a complete MWE (minimum working example -- something that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{documentclass}`).

Comment: It was `\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
{
  {{Company\bibnamedelimb 1\bibnamedelimb name}, },
}` that did it for me. I also got it to work with your `\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}` definition.

Comment: @moewe if you put both company 1 and 2. Does it work? I don't know why in my case it is not working :(

Comment: Yes, I just tried it. If I do the exact same thing for company 2 (that is just make the `1` a `2`) it works for both companies simultaneously.

Comment: I will try again... and if not will try to post a mwe

Comment: @moewe don't ask me why, but it seems that the same code is now working. Sometimes not mastering latex is a real headache ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that cannot be reproduced and appears to be solved now.