# Citation of the British National Corpus (BNC)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am new here but I have been reading along for couple of months now. My biggest problem at the moment is to cite internet sources especially internet webpages.

In my current paper I would like to quote the "British National Corpus". But because of my settings I always get "Corpus, B. N. (2001)" in my bibliography. Is there a way to change that only for that particular case? I would like to get "British National Corpus (2001): Url: . Accessed: 05.04.2015". Unfortunately, "lastchecked" does not appear in my bibliography.

Here my bib-file:

```
    @article{BNC,
    Author = {British National Corpus},
    Date-Added = {2015-05-04 14:58:49 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-05-04 15:10:16 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {04.05.2015},
    Url = {http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk},
    Year = {2001},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk}}
```

Here my settings:

```
\usepackage[style=apa, 
       apabackref=true, 
       backend=biber, 
       hyperref=true, 
       maxnames=1, 
       maxcitenames=6, 
       maxbibnames=99, 
       sorting=debug, 
       natbib=true, 
       language=ngerman, 
       doi=true, 
       url=true 
       ]{biblatex} 


\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}} 
\addbibresource{lit1.bib} 

\NewBibliographyString{retrieved} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{retrieved={Letzter Zugriff am}}

\usepackage{url} 
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100} 
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{100} 
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{100}
```

I have changed my bib-file and added the {{-brackets to the author.

```
article{BNC, Author = {{{British National Corpus}}},
Date-Added = {2015-05-04 14:58:49 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2015-05-04 16:37:05 +0000},
Url = {natcorp.ox.ac.uk},
Urldate = {2015-05-04},
Year = {2001},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {natcorp.ox.ac.uk}} –
```

Unfortunately, I got this:

```
Entity: line 1944: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document <bcf:field>title<
```

And then I cannot compile the file.

I have just seen that there were three {{{ before that is because my BibDesk add one { to each entry automatically. I have fixed that so I only got two {{ now. But I still got the same error.

When I compile the file it says:

```
bbl:95: Paragraph ended before \name was complete. <to be read again> \par l.95?
```

However, line 95 is empty in my file.

Comment: Hi and welcome to yet another LaTeX support page.

Comment: Put the author in extra braces -> `{{British National Corpus}}`

Comment: `lastchecked` iss not valid. Use `urlseen` as mentioned before.

Comment: Please add this information to the question, the edit button is to the left of your name. Code markup in comments is a mess, and it is hard to read your log.

Comment: That is not the same error, and without a minimal working example, it is hard to tell anything. Your original entry does not contain a title field.

Comment: Ok! I got it. It has to be "title" and not "author" then it works! Thank you very much for your help! The two {{ was also important.

Comment: Could you please put together a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), i.e. one that we can just copy & paste and run on our computer. Please make sure that the MWE you post here actually throws the error you describe (sometimes old `.aux`, `.bbl` files cause those).

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you have `sorting=debug,` in your preamble? The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) suggests "[this option] is intended for debugging only." (p. 46)

Comment: The error you get now is because you wrap everything in three pairs of curly braces, two are enough. If you go with the recommended `author = {{British National Corpus}},` everything is fine (after deleting auxiliary files: here deleting the `.bbl` should suffice).

Comment: To be honest I don't know why it says sorting=debug. I got the preamble and use it without knowing every detail. But after I changed author to title it works fine. So I don't really know. I am a beginner.

Comment: If you don't know why it says `sorting=debug` it is best to get rid of that line. If it works now, I'm inclined to vote to close your question as a duplicate of [Using a 'corporate author' in the “author” field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864). BTW: I have opened an issue about the ["three pairs of curly braces cause trouble problem"](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/316).

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much! Thanks also for your advice!