# Citation of International Organisations

Tags: formatting, citing

I am trying to create the following citation for my bibliography using the `apacite` package.

> International Monetary Fund (2014). International Monetary Fund,
>   Annual Report on Exchange Arrangements and Exchange Restrictions
>   (Washington, October 2014).

When using the `apacite` package, I find that rather than appearing as "International Monetary Fund" it appears as "Fund, I.M." as the package assumes that it is a name.

Is there any way in which I can overcome this please?

Comment: Either use `author = {{International Monetary Fund}}` or `organization = {International Monetary Fund}`, given your bibliographystyle supports the `organization` field. Also, it would be easier to help you if you provided a minimal example, with the BIB file and a minimal LaTeX document so that we know, for instance, which BibTeX style you use and how do you code the bibliography entries.

Comment: See also [Using a 'corporate author' in the “author” field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)

Comment: Thank you very much @yo'! Your first suggestion worked brilliantly. I am very new to LaTeX and am actually using overleaf which is why I couldn't provide a Bib file and the minimal LaTeX document. But many thanks again!

Comment: @moewe It seems that the question you linked provides the answer. Rather than writing the same answer here, I voted for duplicating.