# Using institute instead of author for @online

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, online

I'm trying to add [this page](https://data.gov.au/dataset/smart-grid-smart-city-customer-trial-data) to my bibliography.

There is no individual author to attribute, but there is an institute. However the `institute` field seems to not work (it doesn't show up in the bibliography). So I'm trying to put the institute in the `author` field. If I do so, then bibtex tries to format it as a human's name.

So what I want is for the bibliography entry to say:

> Australian Government Department of Industry, Innovation and Science

But what I'm getting is:

> I. Australian Government Department of Industry and Science.

So LaTeX thinks that I'm referencing someone who's first name is `Innovation` and surname is `Australian Government Department of Industry`

I've tried adding lots of `{}` everywhere, but I can't figure out how to override the automatic initialisation.

Minimum working example:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=ieee, natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib} 


\begin{document}

Here's a citation \cite{SGSC_data}.

\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\rmfamily} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

references.bib:

```
@online {SGSC_data,
    year   = "2015",
    month  = 10,
    day    = 8,
    author = "Australian Government Department of Industry, Innovation and Science",
    url    = "https://data.gov.au/dataset/smart-grid-smart-city-customer-trial-data",
    title  = "Smart-Grid Smart-City Customer Trial Data"
}
```

All together with `filecontents` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=ieee, natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@online {SGSC_data,
    year   = "2015",
    month  = 10,
    day    = 8,
    author = "Australian Government Department of Industry, Innovation and Science",
    url    = "https://data.gov.au/dataset/smart-grid-smart-city-customer-trial-data",
    title  = "Smart-Grid Smart-City Customer Trial Data"
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

Here's a citation \cite{SGSC_data}.

\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\rmfamily} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tada `author = {{Australian Government Department of Industry, Innovation and Science}}` see also [Using a 'corporate author' in the “author” field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)

Comment: Please note that with `biblatex` the `day` field does not exists officially and will be discarded starting from the next release, it is far better to use `date = {2015-10-08}`.

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks. I was so close. I tried `author = "{{Australian Government Department of Industry, Innovation and Science}}"`

Comment: Mhh, `author = "{{Australian Government Department of Industry, Innovation and Science}}"` does work here ... Even though it is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: I tried using `date = {2015-10-08}`, but it didn't work. I get the error `Entry 'SGSC_data' (references.bib): Invalid format '2015-10-8' of date field 'date' - ignoring.` and I just see an empty set of brackets in the pdf.

Comment: According to the error message you didn't use `date = {2015-10-08}` but the incorrect `date = {2015-10-8}` (note the missing zero).