# Bibtex journal name not in order

Tags: bibtex

I should have IEEE Journal on Power Systems but it shows Power Systems, IEEE journal on, - How to arrange in correct order. I am using the following style

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

for example in my bib file I have

```
@ARTICLE{1022810,
 author={Zhu and Tomsovic, K.},
 journal={Power Delivery, IEEE Transactions on},
 title={Adaptive power flow method for distribution systems with dispersed generation},
 year={2002},
 volume={17},
 number={3},
 pages={822-827},
,
 doi={10.1109/TPWRD.2002.1022810},
 ISSN={0885-8977},
 month={Jul},}
```

I want the journal name as "IEEE Transactions on Power Delivery" instead of as "Power Delivery, IEEE Transactions on".

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at [Using a 'corporate author' in the “author” field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864). But it would really surprise me if there was a reason to have "IEEE Journal on Power Systems" in the `author` or `editor` field of a `.bib` entry. You will get more specific answers if you can give more details on what you are doing, this is best done in an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the actual entry from your bib file. Please also state which bibliography style file you use.

Comment: In particular, please check if the entry's `journal` field is given as `Power Systems, IEEE journal on`. If that's how the field is given, you'll need to change it by hand to `IEEE journal on Power Systems` in order to get the desired look.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the contents of the bib entry in question and for stating which bibliography style you use.

The `IEEEtran` bibliography style does *not* modify the contents of the `journal` field. Since it is currently given by

```
journal={Power Delivery, IEEE Transactions on},
```

the journal name will be typeset as "Power Delivery, IEEE Transactions on". To get it to be typeset as "IEEE Transactions on Power Delivery", you must modify the field so that it reads as

```
journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Delivery},
```