# How to cite specifications with bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I want to cite following specifications:

```
@article{Committee2014 ,
    author = {Tool Interface Standards},
    file ={:E$\backslash$:/mem{\_}layout{\_}mgr/latex/papers/ELF{\_}Format.pdf:pdf},
    journal = {Specification, Unix System Laboratories},
    title = {Executable and Linkable Format (ELF)},
    url = {http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en{\&}btnG=Search{\&}q=intitle:Executable+and+Linkable+Format+(+ELF+){\#}9},
    edition={1.2},
    year = {2001}
}
```

and

```
@misc{gcccompileprocess,
    author = {NTU},
    title = {GCC and Make Compiling, Linking and Building C/C++ Applications},
    howpublished = "\url{https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html}",
    year = {2013},
}
```

and

```
@misc{memorydefinition,
    author = {Steve Chamberlain},
    title = {Using ld},
    howpublished = "\url{https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html#SEC13}",
    year = {1994}
}
```

One result looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that I do not have any persons as authors, e.g. `Committee2014` and `gcccompileprocess`. How would you cite those examples properly?

Comment: It can't be correct to use the entry type `@article` for the entry with key `Committee2014`. Separately, what do you mean by the entries "do not have any authors"? The first two appear to have so-called corporate authors, and the third would appear to have an author named "Steve Chamberlain". Please clarify.

Comment: Besides Mico's observations, I could add that for corporate authors you can use braces so that it is treated as a block by `bib(la)tex` (that is, an extra set of braces, e.g. `author = {{Tool Interface Standards}},`.

Comment: See also [Using a 'corporate author' in the “author” field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)

Comment: @Mico well, yes I was thinking to keep the author = {} empty.