# biblatex/biber crashes on a \, in the bib-file

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
            backend = biber,
            sortlocale = auto,
            sorting = nty,
            style = authoryear-comp
           ]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{
        Sur,
        author = {Surname, Name},
        editor = {Test e.\,V.},
        title  = {Title},
        year   = {2000},
       }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

  Test \autocite[1]{Sur}.
  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Error log (`bbl` file):

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.9 $
% Do not modify the above lines!

% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
    {Missing 'biblatex' package}
    {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
    \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup

\refsection{0}
  \datalist[entry]{nty/global//global/global}
    \entry{Sur}{book}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,uniquepart=base,hash=4bb983b68767bfb7760064c0db4691d7}{%
        family={Surname},
        familyi={S\bibinitperiod},
        given={Name},
        giveni={N\bibinitperiod},
        givenun=0}}%
      }
      \name{editor}{1}{}{%
        {{hash=f67e6b7b9d22061314a9ed21f1590418}{%
          family={Test\bibnamedelima e.\},
          familyi={T\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim e\bibinitperiod},
          given={V.},
          giveni={V\bibinitperiod}}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{4bb983b68767bfb7760064c0db4691d7}
      \strng{fullhash}{4bb983b68767bfb7760064c0db4691d7}
      \strng{bibnamehash}{4bb983b68767bfb7760064c0db4691d7}
      \strng{authorbibnamehash}{4bb983b68767bfb7760064c0db4691d7}
      \strng{authornamehash}{4bb983b68767bfb7760064c0db4691d7}
      \strng{authorfullhash}{4bb983b68767bfb7760064c0db4691d7}
      \strng{editorbibnamehash}{f67e6b7b9d22061314a9ed21f1590418}
      \strng{editornamehash}{f67e6b7b9d22061314a9ed21f1590418}
      \strng{editorfullhash}{f67e6b7b9d22061314a9ed21f1590418}
      \field{sortinit}{S}
      \field{sortinithash}{322b1d5276f2f6c1bccdcd15920dbee6}
      \field{extradatescope}{labelyear}
      \field{labeldatesource}{year}
      \field{labelnamesource}{author}
      \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
      \field{title}{Title}
      \field{year}{2000}
    \endentry
  \enddatalist
\endrefsection
\endinput
```

Is `\,` not allowed in `bib` files or is it a bug?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: Protect the editor with additional braces: {{Test e.\,V.}} (untested, I don't have time now).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. One could argue that this is a bug since Biber should probably not produce something that breaks so spectacularly. But then again the whole initial generation is vastly complicated and you should use double braces as in `editor = {{Test e.\,V.}},` anyway - in which case it works, so I don't think we need to lose sleep over this.

Comment: Hello @Ulrike Fischer! Your advice works! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex` has its own macro. From its documentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
            backend = biber,
            sortlocale = auto,
            sorting = nty,
            style = authoryear-comp
           ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{
        Sur,
        author = {Surname, Name},
        editor = {{Test e.\addnbthinspace{}V.}},
        title  = {Title},
        year   = {2000},
       }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

  Test \autocite[1]{Sur}.
  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

*Please note that using `biblatex` specific commands in the .bib file means that the .bib file can only be used with `biblatex` and is no longer compatible with other bibliography tools*

Comment: But you should still use double braces `editor = {{Test e.\addnbthinspace{}V.}},` so that the name does not get split. In that case even `editor = {{Test e.\.V.}},` works.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. There is an argument for choosing `\,` over `\addnbthinspace` to be made here: It makes the `.bib` file more portable.

Comment: One could use providecommand though.