# Organization/Group as author - getting the shorthand form right

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm using the `alpha` bibliography style in a document of mine. Now, I have the following entry in my `.bib` file:

```
@misc{foo,
  key          = {Frobnicating the bar},
  author       = {The Foo Team},
  year         = {2018},
  note         = {\url{https://www.foo.com/whatever}}
}
```

I'm not using `natbib`, nor `biblatex` nor anything like that. What I get is:

> [tea18] The foo team. Frobincating the bar. https://www.foo.com/whatever

The entry is fine - except for the shorthand. I'm actually not sure what I even want it to be, but definitely not "tea" as though it was some person whose last name is "team".

Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: In name fields you should write `author = {{The Foo Team}},` to make sure the name is treated as a unit and not parsed as the name of a person with last name "Team" and first names "The Foo", see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. Since the `alpha` style gives `author` preference over the `key` field when producing labels for `@misc` I can't see a way to override the label if you want to stick to `author` (which probably makes sense).

Comment: Any news here? Was the issue resolved?

Comment: @schtandard: I used my own answer and that works; have not inquired further...

Answer (score 2):

One option: Make "The Foo Team" an organization, not an author. You'll lose mention of them in the entry, but the shorthand should become `[Fro18]`.