# Apacite also printing first name when there is one author

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, apacite

I am using the `apacite` package to write my thesis. I've noticed that when I only have 1 author as a reference, it also prints the first name. According to the APA guidelines this should not be the case. Does anyone know why it's happening?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\begin{document}  

According to \citet{Oxfam} ...

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

`bib.bib`

```
@misc{Oxfam,
author = "{Jon Slater}",
title = "Annual income of richest 100 people enough to end global poverty four times over",
year = "2013",
howpublished = "{\url{https://www.oxfam.org/en/pressroom/pressreleases/2013-01-19/annual-income-richest-100-people-enough-end-global-poverty-four}}"
note = {Accessed: 2018-09-17}
```

**Text output:**

According to Jon Slater (2013),

Comment: Do not use curly braces *and* quotation marks (or double curly braces for that matter) for a field: Use either `author = "Jon Slater",` or `author = {Jon Slater},`. If you use `author = "{Jon Slater}",` `Jon Slater` will be treated as a unit (as a person with the family name "Jon Slater" and no first name).

Comment: Wow I did not know that. My bad :) It's working now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write either

```
author = {Jon Slater},
```

or

```
author = "Jon Slater",
```

If you use both quotation marks and curly braces as in

```
author = "{Jon Slater}",
```

the author is not a person with first name *Jon* and last name *Slater*, instead BibTeX will parse the name as one unit, i.e. as someone whose last name is *Jon Slater* and who has no first name. This is very convenient for *corporate authors* (see [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)), but (almost) never what you want for people's names.

---

In none-name fields the construction

```
<field> = "{<contents>}",
```

does not mess up name parsing, but might completely inhibit the sentence case feature. Read more about it at [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864). I strongly suggest not using a style that applies sentence case if you don't want sentence case instead of wrapping the entire contents of a field in braces.

In the example `howpublished` does not really gain a lot from `"{...}"`, `"..."` or `{...}` would be enough.