# Protect names from being abbreviated

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

LaTeX thinks the name of organisations are first names, which are abbreviated using my bibliography style.

```
@Misc{BundesministeriumfuerUmwelt,
author = {Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Naturschutz und nukleare Sicherheit (BMU)},
title  = {Klimaschutzplan 2050. Klimaschutzpolitische Grundsätze und Ziele der Bundesregierung},
date   = {11.2016},}
```

Therefore comes out as

```
N. u.n.S. B. Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Klimaschutzplan 2050.
klimaschutzpolitische grundsätze und ziele der bundesregierung.
```

Using

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
```

How can the name be protected in a case like this?

Also, I would like to know if there is a simpler way of protecting the capitalizations of the references titles than putting everything in curly brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So-called corporate authors need to be protected by a pair of curly braces to avoid that BibTeX or Biber tries to parse the name as the name of a person with family and given names. See [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864). So you need

```
author   = {{Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Naturschutz und nukleare Sicherheit (BMU)}},
```

`biblatex-ieee` applies sentence casing to some titles and so "Klimaschutzplan 2050. Klimaschutzpolitische Grundsätze und Ziele der Bundesregierung" will be converted to "Klimaschutzplan 2050. klimaschutzpolitische grundsätze und ziele der bundesregierung". The English rules of sentence case that `biblatex` applies here make no sense of a German text, so the best we can do is tell `biblatex` that this is a German title that should not need any case changes. This is done by adding

```
langid = {ngerman},
```

to the entry. In case you do have an English title where sentence casing should apply, but you need to protect a few proper names or acronyms from case change, you will, however, need curly braces again. See [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864).

Finally, note that `date = {11.2016},` is the wrong input format for `date`-like fields. `biblatex` expects date input in `YYYY-MM-DD` format of ISO 8601. So

```
date = {2016-11},
```

would be the expected input.

Putting this all together

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{bmu,
  author   = {{Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Naturschutz und nukleare Sicherheit (BMU)}},
  title    = {Klimaschutzplan 2050},
  subtitle = {Klimaschutzpolitische Grundsätze und Ziele der Bundesregierung},
  date     = {2016-11},
  langid   = {ngerman},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,bmu}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde, ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’, Journal of Computational Chemistry, vol. 19, no. 4, pp. 377–395, 1998.//Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Naturschutz und nukleare Sicherheit (BMU), Klimaschutzplan 2050, Klimaschutzpolitische Grundsätze und Ziele der Bundesregierung, Nov. 2016.]

Note that BibTeX is considered a *legacy* backend now and that only Biber supports all of `biblatex`'s features. So you may want to consider switching from `backend=bibtex` to `backend=biber`. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help on getting your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX for you. [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) has a bit of background, so does [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).