# Problem with a reference not appearing correctly in the pdf

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am citing the following source but the author's full name does not appear in the text. It only produces "for Management of Antiretroviral Therapy (SMART)" as author's name in the citation. I am not sure what's wrong.

```
@article{strategies2006cd4+,
  title={CD4+ count--guided interruption of antiretroviral treatment},
  author={Strategies for Management of Antiretroviral Therapy (SMART) Study Group},
  journal={New England Journal of Medicine},
  volume={355},
  number={22},
  pages={2283--2296},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Mass Medical Soc}
}
```

Comment: Try `author={{Strategies for Management of Antiretroviral Therapy (SMART) Study Group}},` if this does not help, please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: That solved my problem! Thanks. If you could post your comment as an answer, I would want to accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate to: [Using a 'corporate author' in the “author” field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/134144)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the author consists of different name parts like first name and last name. Your bibliography tool tries to automatically divide the name in these parts, which does not work for a cooperate author as you have in your example.

To tell your bibliography tool that the whole author is only a single name part, you can wrap it in an additional set of `{}`:

```
@article{strategies2006cd4+,
  title={CD4+ count--guided interruption of antiretroviral treatment},
  author={{Strategies for Management of Antiretroviral Therapy (SMART) Study Group}},
  journal={New England Journal of Medicine},
  volume={355},
  number={22},
  pages={2283--2296},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Mass Medical Soc}
}
```