# If no author use organization or institution

Tags: biblatex

I would like to make some amendments to my entries.

If there is no author, editor or translator, but an institution or organization, this should replace the placement of the author. So it should be at the front, in small caps. This should apply for all types of entries.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIB
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    sorting=nyvt, 
    maxnames=25,
    dashed=false, 
    isbn=false
  ]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{library.bib}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\renewcommand\postnotedelim{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [thesis]
  {title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}  % thesis title italic


% no period after addon titles
\usepackage{xpatch}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{titleaddondelim}{\addspace}
\xpatchbibmacro{title}
  {\printfield{titleaddon}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{titleaddondelim}}%
   \printfield{titleaddon}}
  {}
  {}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{booktitleaddondelim}{\addspace}    
\xpatchbibmacro{booktitle}
  {\printfield{booktitleaddon}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{titleaddondelim}}%
   \printfield{booktitleaddon}}
  {}
  {}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{maintitleaddondelim}{\addspace}  
\xpatchbibmacro{maintitle}
  {\printfield{maintitleaddon}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{titleaddondelim}}%
   \printfield{maintitleaddon}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

Test Entries:

```
@article{journal.1981,
 journal = {University Shimbun},
 institution = {Test Institution},
 year = {1981},
 pages = {20},
 location = {Kanagawa},
 note = {Morgenausgabe},
 title = {University Paper Title}
} 

@article{journalb.1981,
     journal = {University Shimbun},
     organization = {Test Organization},
     year = {1981},
     pages = {20},
     location = {Kanagawa},
     note = {Morgenausgabe},
     title = {University Paper Title}
    }
```

Current result:

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: that's an interesting way to see it! I probably overthought the issue here. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the exact situation and I can't quite tell from the toy example in the question, but in general I recommend to give the organisation/institution in the `author` (or `editor`, `translator`) field if it was involved in authoring (or editing, translating) the work.

It is perfectly acceptable to have "corporate authors" as long as you remember to protect them in curly braces to avoid having their names parsed as personal names. See [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864).

What matters when you populate the `author` field is not whether or not the author is a person or a corporate entity. What matters is the role they played in producing the work, their authorship.

Note further that `organization` and `institution` are fields not supported by every entry type. In general it is fair to say they are a 'replacement' for `publisher` where `publisher` is not fully appropriate. For example for `@thesis` entries `institution` or its legacy alias `school` take exactly the role of `publisher`. `@online` entries also have an `organization`. `@report`s have an `institution`. An exception is `@(in)proceedings` where `organization` is the organisation organising the conference and `publisher` the publisher of the conference proceedings. `organization` and `institution` are not intended as alternatives for `author` or `editor` if they happen to be a corporate entity.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIB
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    sorting=nyvt, 
    maxnames=25,
    dashed=false, 
    isbn=false
  ]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\renewcommand\postnotedelim{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [thesis]
  {title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}  % thesis title italic


% no period after addon titles
\usepackage{xpatch}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{titleaddondelim}{\addspace}
\xpatchbibmacro{title}
  {\printfield{titleaddon}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{titleaddondelim}}%
   \printfield{titleaddon}}
  {}
  {}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{booktitleaddondelim}{\addspace}    
\xpatchbibmacro{booktitle}
  {\printfield{booktitleaddon}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{titleaddondelim}}%
   \printfield{booktitleaddon}}
  {}
  {}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{maintitleaddondelim}{\addspace}  
\xpatchbibmacro{maintitle}
  {\printfield{maintitleaddon}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{titleaddondelim}}%
   \printfield{maintitleaddon}}
  {}
  {}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{journal.1981,
  journal  = {University Shimbun},
  author   = {{Test Institution}},
  year     = {1981},
  pages    = {20},
  location = {Kanagawa},
  note     = {Morgenausgabe},
  title    = {University Paper Title},
} 

@article{journalb.1981,
  journal  = {University Shimbun},
  author   = {{Test Organization}},
  year     = {1981},
  pages    = {20},
  location = {Kanagawa},
  note     = {Morgenausgabe},
  title    = {University Paper Title}
} 
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

[image: "Test Institution (1981): University Paper Title. In: University Shimbun. Morgenausgabe, S. 20.//Test Organization (1981): University Paper Title. In: University Shimbun. Morgenausgabe, S. 20." "Test Institution" and "Test Organization" are in small caps.]