# How to automatically disambiguate identical bibliography keys in custom bibliography style?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to reproduce my university bibliography style in biblatex.

In the bibliography, every entry is prefixed with label in parentheses which consists of institution or authors, year and cited page (optional).
When there are two entries with the same institution or authors and the same year, the year should be suffixed with consecutive letters as pictured below:

[image: university template]

At this point, the code generating bibliography looks as follows:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{%
  \list{%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \printlist{institution}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
      \printnames[author-label][-2]{author}%
      \setunit*{,\addspace}%
      \printfield{year}%
      \iffieldundef{thiscite}{}
        {\addcomma\space\printfield{thiscite}}%
    }%
    \enspace---\enspace%
  }{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
    \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}
}{\endlist}{\item}
```

…which produces the following:

[image: illustration of bibliography environment]

I was only able to find partial snippets in the biblatex documentation, but there was no concrete example, so I was not able to make anything out of it.

How can I check if there are two labels with the same institution/authors and year and insert suffix after the year?

### MWE

`wsb.bbx`:

```
\ProvidesFile{wsb.bbx}[2020/01/11 WSB bibliography style]

\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=range, skipout=false]{thiscite}
\DeclareFieldFormat{thiscite}{\mkpageprefix{#1}}

\def\printname{\usebibmacro{name:family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}
\DeclareNameFormat{author-label}{%
  % If there are more than three names, print only the first one
  \ifmorenames%
    {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
      {\printname{} \bibstring{andothers}}
      {}}
    {\printname{}}%
}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \namepartfamily%
  \ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}
    {}{\addcomma\space\namepartgiveni}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\value{liststop}}
    {}{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{%
  \list{%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \printlist{institution}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
      \printnames[author-label][-2]{author}%
      \setunit*{,\addspace}%
      \printfield{year}%
      \iffieldundef{thiscite}{}
        {\addcomma\space\printfield{thiscite}}%
    }%
    \enspace---\enspace%
  }{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
    \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}
}{\endlist}{\item}

\newbibmacro*{institution+author+year}{%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit{,\addspace}%
  \printfield{year}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \usebibmacro{institution+author+year}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitle}{}
    {\usebibmacro{in:}%
      \printfield{journaltitle}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit\newblock%
\finentry}
```

`mve.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[
    bibstyle=wsb,
    sortcites=true,
    sorting=nty,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@report{gus_2016,
    title = "Działalność innowacyjna przedsiębiorstw w~latach 2013-2016",
    institution = "GUS",
    url = "http://stat.gov.pl/obszary-tematyczne/nauka-i-technikaspoleczenstwo-informacyjne/nauka-i-technika/dzialanosc-innowacyjnaprzedsiebiorstw-w-latach-2013-2015,2,14.html",
    urldate = "2017-07-18",
    thiscite = "3",
    year = 2016,
}

@report{gus_2016a,
    title = "Badanie organizacji i~rozkładu czasu pracy w~Polsce w~2015 roku",
    institution = "GUS",
    url = "http://stat.gov.pl/obszary-tematyczne/rynekpracy/opracowania/badanie-organizacji-i-rozkladu-czasu-pracy-wpolsce-w-2015-r-,12,1.html",
    urldate = "2017-07-18",
    thiscite = "38",
    year = 2016,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
Citation number one \cite{gus_2016}.

Citation number two \cite{gus_2016a}.

\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to look into basing your style onto `authoryear` (check out `authoryear.bbx` and `authoryear.cbx`). Biber can calculate uniqueness information and add disambiguation letters where required (`extradate` info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you base your style on `authoryear` or one of its derivatives. `biblatex` (or rather Biber/BibTeX) automatically calculate uniqueness information for author/editor-year combinations and make them available in the `extradate` field (which is automatically printed with `\printlabeldateextra`, `\printdateextra` and friends).

Then the repetition of the citation in the bibliography can be implemented as in my `biblatex-ext` styles (the `introcite=plain,` feature). This made it possible to remove a few now unused macros.

There are some smaller changes to the style as well

- It is good practice to make sure that all bibliography drivers start with `\usebibmacro{bibindex}\usebibmacro{begentry}` and end with `\usebibmacro{finentry}`.
- Data model commands need to be in a separate `.dbx` file.

Finally, I changed the field for `GUS` in the example entries from `institution` to `author`. `author` and `editor` are functional roles, so if the author was an institution, there is no reason not to include it there. The `institution` and `organization` fields are similar in role to the `publisher` field. Compare also [If no author use organization or institution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480431/35864).

In total (with `.bbx`, `.cbx`, `.dbx` file produced by inline `filecontents` to make the example self contained)

```
\documentclass[polish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{wsb.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{wsb.bbx}[2020/01/24 WSB bibliography style]

\RequireBibliographyStyle{authortitle}

\DeclareFieldFormat{thiscite}{\mkpageprefix{#1}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:introcite}{\usebibmacro{cite}}

\newcommand*{\extblx@introcite@init}{%
  \iftoggle{blx@citation}
    {}
    {\togglefalse{blx@bibliography}%
     \toggletrue{blx@citation}}%
  \delimcontext{bbx@introcite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \undef\cbx@lasthash
  \undef\cbx@lastyear
  \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \defcounter{minnames}{\blx@mincitenames}%
}

\newbibmacro{introcite:typeset}{%
  \begingroup
    \extblx@introcite@init
    \printtext[bbx@introcite]{\usebibmacro{bbx:introcite}}%
  \endgroup
}

\newbibmacro{introcite:plain}{%
  \usebibmacro{introcite:typeset}%
  \printunit*{\introcitepunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\newcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\enspace---\enspace}%

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
  \usebibmacro{introcite:plain}}


\newbibmacro*{institution+author+year}{%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{institution+author+year}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{in:}%
      \printfield{journaltitle}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{wsb.cbx}
\ProvidesFile{wsb.cbx}[2020/01/24 WSB citation style]

\RequireCitationStyle{authoryear}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=inline}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{wsb.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{wsb.dbx}[2020/01/24 WSB bib/cite style data model]

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=range, skipout=false]{thiscite}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{thiscite}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  style=wsb,
  sortcites=true,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@report{gus_2016,
  title       = {Działalność innowacyjna przedsiębiorstw w~latach 2013-2016},
  author      = {GUS},
  url         = {http://stat.gov.pl/obszary-tematyczne/nauka-i-technikaspoleczenstwo-informacyjne/nauka-i-technika/dzialanosc-innowacyjnaprzedsiebiorstw-w-latach-2013-2015,2,14.html},
  urldate     = {2017-07-18},
  thiscite    = {3},
  year        = 2016,
}
@report{gus_2016a,
  title       = {Badanie organizacji i~rozkładu czasu pracy w~Polsce w~2015 roku},
  author      = {GUS},
  url         = {http://stat.gov.pl/obszary-tematyczne/rynekpracy/opracowania/badanie-organizacji-i-rozkladu-czasu-pracy-wpolsce-w-2015-r-,12,1.html},
  urldate     = {2017-07-18},
  thiscite    = {38},
  year        = 2016,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Citation number one \autocite{gus_2016}.

Citation number two \autocite{gus_2016a}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (GUS, 2016a) — GUS, 2016. Badanie organizacji i rozkładu czasu pracy w Polsce w 2015 roku, url: http://stat.gov.pl/obszary-tematyczne/rynekpracy/opracowania/badanie-organizacji-i-rozkladu-czasu-pracy-wpolsce-w-2015-r-,12,1.html (term. wiz. 18.07.2017).//(GUS, 2016b) — GUS, 2016. Działalność innowacyjna przedsiębiorstw w latach 2013-2016, url: http://stat.gov.pl/obszary-tematyczne/nauka-i-technikaspoleczenstwo-informacyjne/nauka-i-technika/dzialanosc-innowacyjnaprzedsiebiorstw-w-latach-2013-2015,2,14.html (term. wiz. 18.07.2017).]

Comment: What do these lines do?
`\undef\cbx@lasthash
\undef\cbx@lastyear`
I have seen them used in `authoryear.bbx`, but I could not find any explanation in the documentation. Also, why do you disable trackers in the next line?

Thank you for the answer and corrections. I will accept the answer as soon as I will apply it in my bibliography style.

Comment: I have tried to compile your example, but I have an error "Missing \begin{document}" on the line with `\begin{filecontents*}[force]{\jobname.bib}`

Comment: I had to remove `[force]` from the code.

Comment: @CzarekDrożak `[force]` was introduced in LaTeX version `2019-10-01`, so if you are using an older version that might produce errors. I wanted to remove all `[force]` options anyway to avoid overwriting stuff, but forgot that one. Will edit in a sec.

Comment: @CzarekDrożak `\cbx@lasthash` and `\cbx@lastyear` are used in some styles to implement the citation `-comp` feature, which turns "(Knuth 1984, Knuth 1986)" into "(Knuth 1984, 1986)". This is not desired when the citation is repeated in the bibliography and needs  to be turned off. Same for some of the tracking features. I copied the code from `biblatex-ext`, where it has to deal with all sort of styles and situations, not all of the precautions may be needed in your case.