# Issues with references in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing my thesis in electrical engineering and using IEEE Tran standard. I'm referencing a simple datasheet online but I can't get the references list to show the corporation name instead of an author style name. For example "Adafruit Industries" becomes "A. Industries".

[image]

I use JabRef and the way I create my file is shown below.

```
@Misc{LiPoDatasheet,
author       = {SHENZHEN PKCELL BATTERY},
title        = {Li-Polymer Battery Technology Specification},
howpublished = {\url{https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/328/P328_-_Li-Polymer_785060_2500mAh_3.7V_with_PCM.pdf}},
year         = {2014},
}
```

I have tried using @Standard and  @Manual as well. The problems I face then are no quotes around the title and missing URL.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864

Comment: I see that I duplicated that question, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply putting the "author" (company name) in an additional set of braces should work:

```
@Misc{LiPoDatasheet,
author       = {{SHENZHEN PKCELL BATTERY}},
title        = {Li-Polymer Battery Technology Specification},
howpublished = {\url{https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/328/P328_-_Li-Polymer_785060_2500mAh_3.7V_with_PCM.pdf}},
year         = {2014},
}
```

The same technique can also be used around parts of an author name, or any other field (title, booktitle, whatever) to force a certain way of writing (for instance, to force using capitalisation when a certain bibliographystyle would otherwise refuse to use capital letters somewhere).

For example, if you also really want the same capitalisation for the publication title to be used (starting every word with a capital), you could do this:

```
@Misc{LiPoDatasheet,
author       = {{SHENZHEN PKCELL BATTERY}},
title        = {Li-{P}olymer {B}attery {T}echnology {S}pecification},
howpublished = {\url{https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/328/P328_-_Li-Polymer_785060_2500mAh_3.7V_with_PCM.pdf}},
year         = {2014},
}
```

Comment: This worked amazing.