# How to make referencing @manual display only what is specified in the parentheses

Tags: bibliographies

I have a manual reference:

```
@manual{GICSmanual,
author = "Standard \& Poor's Financial Services, Morgan Stanley Capital International",
title = "Global Industry Classification Standard",
pagetotal = "46"
}
```

In the References table, it appears with an additional text "|Computer software manual|":

[image]

I should not specify that it is a computer software manual. I do not know why this appears, I did not pass anywhere that this is a computer software manual. I also looked to see if "computer software manual" is referenced somewhere else in my references and it is not. Any ideas why this appears?

Comment: It would appear that your bibliography style adds the "computer software manual" automatically for entries of type `@manual` (possibly unless you do something to prevent it). There are many bibliography packages and styles out there and if there is a solution (and what that solution could be) will depend on the package and style you use. Please show us a short example document that reproduces the output you see (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: It won't help with the issue at hand, but you definitely want to write `author = "{Standard \& Poor's Financial Services, Morgan Stanley Capital International}",` to avoid BibTeX parsing the `author` field as the name of a person and trying to abbreviate the 'first' name, which leads to the "M. S. C. I.". See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864

Comment: As a quick fix you can try `@misc` instead of `@manual`.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for the suggestion. It works now. I still didn't figured out why it did that, but as long as it works...

Comment: @Adrian the bibliography style that you use defines how each entry type is displayed, apparently this definition included the phrase _Computer software manual_ for entries of type `@manual`. For entries of type `@misc` bibliography styles normally do not add anything, that's why I made the suggestion. Other solutions would have been to choose another bibliography style, or to modify the definitions of the current style.