# BibLatex Citing with Author having "And" in Name

Tags: biblatex

So I'm trying to cite an "author" that has "and" in its name. By "author", I mean more like a department. I'm citing a paper written by the U.S. Department of Health and Human Services along with the Food and Drug Administration. I looked all over the paper and I could not see any other author but regardless, how do you cite an author that has "And" in its name. I feel like I may be able to do it if I go with "@manual" in the .bib file but I'm trying to see if its possible with "@online" or "@author".

Comment: put the full names in braces, so `author={{U.S. Department of Health and Human Services} and {Food and Drug Administration}},`.

Comment: Corporate authors need to be wrapped in an additional pair of curly braces: `author = {{U.S. Department of Health and Human Services} and {Food and Drug Administration}},`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864

Comment: This behaviour is independent of the entry type you use (`@article`, `@online`, `@manual`) and is documented in §2.3.3 *Corporate Authors and Editors*, pp. 33-34 of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't know what to google and I was utilizing the brackets but had commas so it threw the error too many commas. Or maybe my code was just broken in general and that's why is threw the errors.