# References lists wrong

Tags: cross-referencing

I am using this reference

```
@online{br18,
author = "Trafik, Bygge, Boligstyrelsen",
title = "Bygningsreglement 2018",
url  = "https://bygningsreglementet.dk/Tekniske-bestemmelser/17/Vejledninger/Generel_vejledning",
addendum = "(accessed: 26.02.2020)",
keywords = "br18"
}
```

But i would like the reference author to be "Trafik, bygge og boligstyrelsen."
But for some reason it shows up wrong?

I am using \bibliographystyle{plain}

Comment: Put it in parantheses `author =  {Trafik, bygge og boligstyrelsen}`

Comment: @thewaywewalk thanks, that worked!

Comment: In fact it should probably be `author = {{Trafik, bygge og boligstyrelsen}},` with two pairs of curly braces. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. `author = {Trafik, bygge og boligstyrelsen}` just accidentally works because it has fewer commas than `author = "Trafik, Bygge, Boligstyrelsen",`.