# How do I make it print out the titleaddon in the reference list instead of defaulting to the title when there are no authors?

Tags: biblatex

Here is the existing document code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, final, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp,sorting=nyt,isbn=false,doi=true,dashed=false,maxbibnames=99,uniquename=init,giveninits]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referenser.bib}
\DeclareLabeltitle{%
\field{titleaddon}
\field{shorttitle}
\field{title}
\field{maintitle}
}

\begin{document}
Here is one sentence.\parencite{Knuth:ct-a}

Here is another sentence.\parencite{noauthor_solcell_2020}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the `.bib` file:

```
@Book{Knuth:ct-a,
author =       "Donald E. Knuth",
title =        "The {\TeX}book",
publisher =    "Addison-Wesley",
year =         "1986",
volume =       "A",
series =       "Computers and Typesetting",
pages =        "ix + 483",
}

@online{noauthor_solcell_2020,
titleaddon = {Nationalencyklopedin},
title = {solcell},
url = {https://www.ne.se/uppslagsverk/encyklopedi/l%C3%A5ng/solcell},
urldate = {2020-04-13},
date = {2020}
}
```

As of now it prints out:

[image]

How do I make it print out *Nationalencyklopedin* in the reference list instead of the title *solcell* when there are no authors?

I used the `\DeclareLabletitle` to make *Nationalencyklopedin* print instead of the title in the text. Is there some similar way to change the reference list as well?

As I do not fully understand what is happening in the code above could you show where it is safe to put these changes in my code for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my answer to [Why is biblatex defaulting to using title instead of author when no author is provided and how do I change it to using journaltitle instead?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538475/35864) it is perfectly fine to "upgrade" corporate authors like *Nationalencyklopedin* to the `author` of your `@online` entry.

```
\documentclass[12pt, final, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp,
  maxbibnames=99, uniquename=init, giveninits,
  dashed=false,
  isbn=false, doi=true,]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knuth:ct-a,
  author    = {Donald E. Knuth},
  title     = {The {\TeX}book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year      = {1986},
  volume    = {A},
  maintitle = {Computers and Typesetting},
  pagetotal = {ix + 483},
}
@online{noauthor_solcell_2020,
  author     = {Nationalencyklopedin},
  title      = {solcell},
  url        = {https://www.ne.se/uppslagsverk/encyklopedi/l%C3%A5ng/solcell},
  urldate    = {2020-04-13},
  date       = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Here is one sentence. \autocite{Knuth:ct-a}

Here is another sentence. \autocite{noauthor_solcell_2020}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Nationalencyklopedin (2020). solcell. url: https://www.ne.se/uppslagsverk/encyklopedi/l%C3%A5ng/solcell (visited on 04/13/2020).]

I can understand that it may not feel quite right to put *Nationalencyklopedin* down as an editor, but it certainly gives the best results here.

In theory you could also use the `label` field that serves as a fallback in case no `author`, `editor` or `translator` is given.

```
@online{noauthor_solcell_2020,
  label     = {Nationalencyklopedin},
  title     = {solcell},
  url       = {https://www.ne.se/uppslagsverk/encyklopedi/l%C3%A5ng/solcell},
  urldate   = {2020-04-13},
  date      = {2020},
}
```

The disadvantage of the `label` field is that Biber can not perform uniqueness calculations with `label` and so you may end up with two identical labels for different entries if you cite two *Nationalencyklopedin*s articles from 2020. So I can't really recommend `label` here.