# Biblatex field organization not showing in footcite

Tags: biblatex, macros

I'm trying to renew the macro for my footcite. For Books and others it works as aspected. But for type online I have some problems.

I want to show the author and if no author exists, I want to display the organization.

> author/organization, year, "Onlinequelle"

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifentrytype{online}%
    {
    \iffieldundef{author}
      {\printnames{labelname}}
      {\printlist{organization}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    \printtext[]{Onlinequelle}
    }
   {
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}
        }
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
       \ifboolexpr{   test {\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
                 or test {\iffieldequalstr{labelyear}{nodate}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:labeltitle}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    }
```

I get this result:
[image]

```
@Online{Inc2015,
  citationkey  = {Inc2015},
  title        = {Class ArrayList<E>},
  url          = {https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html},
  year         = {2015},
  note         = {in: Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 7 API Specification},
  organization = {Oracle America Inc.},
  urldate      = {2021-01-03},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`author` is a name field, so you need to ask with `\ifnameundef` if it is given, not with `\iffieldundef`. Since `author` is not a field, but a name list, `\iffieldundef{author}` always gives true, so your code never gets to `\printlist{organization}`. You need to use `\ifnameundef` here.

Since you print `labelname`, you probably shouldn't be testing for `author`, but for `labelname` instead.

In total

```
    \iffieldundef{author}
      {\printnames{labelname}}
      {\printlist{organization}}
```

should be

```
    \ifnameundef{labelname}
      {\printnames{labelname}}
      {\printlist{organization}}%
```

---

The code shown in the question is likely to produce several spurious spaces because it is missing `%` to comment out line ends. Read more about why you need to add `%` at the end of some lines in [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864).

Streamlining some other bits of the code and using the indentation style of the `biblatex` standard styles, I would probably write your code as

```
\NewBibliographyString{onlineresource}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  onlineresource = {Onlinequelle},
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifentrytype{online}%
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printnames{labelname}}
       {\printlist{organization}}
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \bibstring{onlineresource}}
   {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\ifnameundef{labelname}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
         {\printnames{labelname}%
          \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
       \iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{nodate}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:labeltitle}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
```

(Untested, because you did not provide an example document for testing.)

---

In cases like this I think it is usually perfectly fine to "upgrade" the `organization` to `author` (or `editor` if that is more appropriate). There is no rule against using organisations or corporations in the `author` or `editor` field ([Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)), so a non-person author should not *automatically* be pushed off into the `organization` field. `author` and `editor` are fields that describe the *function* or *role* of an entity, not their ontological properties. If an organization/non-person takes over that role, then it is perfectly fine to name them as such in the `.bib` file. The `organization` field, on the other hand, is much more similar to the `publisher` field. See also my comments in [Cite Publisher and Date when no author is available - eg. website](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/539350/35864), [If no author use organization or institution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480431/35864) and [Why is biblatex defaulting to using title instead of author when no author is provided and how do I change it to using journaltitle instead?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538475/35864).

Using `author`/`editor` here instead of `organization` not only makes the code for the `cite` macro simpler, it also won't require structurally similar changes to the bibliography driver.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your effort for this answer. Also, a lot of additional information given!