# Not able to reference an image URL

Tags: bibtex

I have been trying to reference an image URL using BibTex. Please find below minimum working example(MWE).

I have the following entry in my `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\input{background}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{main}
\end{document}
```

Following is the separate `background.tex` file. I have cited the image url as shown below:

```
% !TEX root =  main.tex

\chapter{Background}
\label{chap:backround}

 About clusters in Apache Spark:

\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{cluster_overview}
    \centering
    \caption{Spark stack (\cite{clustermodeoverview})}
 \end{figure}
```

Below is a snippet of `main.bib` file:

```
@article{afrati2001generating,
  title={Generating efficient plans for queries using views},
  author={Afrati, Foto N and Li, Chen and Ullman, Jeffrey D},
  journal={ACM SIGMOD Record},
  volume={30},
  number={2},
  pages={319--330},
  year={2001},
  publisher={ACM New York, NY, USA}
}
@inproceedings{herodotou2011query,
  title={Query optimization techniques for partitioned tables},
  author={Herodotou, Herodotos and Borisov, Nedyalko and Babu, Shivnath},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 2011 ACM SIGMOD International Conference on Management of data},
  pages={49--60},
  year={2011}
}


@misc{clustermodeoverview,
    author  = {Spark 2.4.5 documentation},
    title   = {Cluster mode overview},
    year    = {2019},
    url     = {https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/img/cluster-overview.png}
    }
```

I always get a warning "Citation 'clustermodeoverview' on page 5 undefined". There are no errors on compilation. Also, I observed that there is no entry for URL citation in my "Bibliography" page. All other citations of research papers are showing up properly.

I have included `url` package in `main.tex`. I have tried to search for the reason of this warning but could not fix it. Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Add a `\protect` before `\cite{}`.

Comment: @Roboticist Still getting the same problem with it :(

Comment: Why don't you present a compilable snippet?

Comment: Delete `.bbl` and recompile?

Comment: Citations in `\caption`s can be tricky, but if things there go wrong, they usually go wrong in a way that causes a real error message, not just `Citation 'clustermodeoverview' on page 5 undefined`. Are there any other errors or warnings in your `.log` file? Did you run LaTeX, LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX on your document after you added the citation? Unfortunately, it is hard to give any further advice, because so far the question only contains code snippets and not a full example document. The snippets leave to much room for guessing. We need an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/

Comment: Some older BibTeX styles don't support a `url` field, which could explain why the URL is not shown in the bibliography at the end. We can only say if that is the problem, though, if you tell us what bibliography style you are using (this is best done in an MWE, see my comment above).

Comment: @moewe I have added MWE as suggested. Hope that helps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Roboticist I have now added a MWE.

Comment: Please test the MWE and make sure that it produces *exactly* the behaviour you are asking about. When I run the MWE I get an error about `\includegraphics` because the example doesn't load `graphicx`.

Comment: When I add the missing `\usepackage{graphicx}` I get a citation in the caption and no warning about undefined citations. As suspected you are using one of the standard BibTeX styles, which can not deal with URLs in the `url` field. You can either switch to a more modern style (for example `abbrvnat` with `\usepackage{natbib}`) or put the URL into the `howpublished` field.

Comment: In the bibliography that I get `author  = {Spark 2.4.5 documentation},` looks very odd. If you write stuff into the `author` field that is not a person's name, you need to protect it with braces `author  = {{Spark 2.4.5 documentation}},`. But `Spark 2.4.5 documentation` doesn't appear to be an author anyway. (Cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)

Comment: @moewe thank you :) I have modified the `.bib` entry as suggested. Now it displays the correct references. But in the Bibliography page it doesn't display the URL. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: As I wrote above: The style you use `abbrv` dates back to the eighties, when URLs weren't a big thing yet. `abbrv` simply does not support a `url` field. You could use the standard workaround `howpublished = {\url{https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/img/cluster-overview.png}},` or use a different style that supports the `url` field. (There are many such styles, for example [`urlbst`](https://ctan.org/pkg/urlbst)'s `abbrvurl`, but I would probably start looking at `natbib`: load `\usepackage{natbib}` and use `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108359/discussion-between-a-beginner-and-moewe).