# Sorting of Tibetan author name Si tu Chos koi ’byung gnas

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I am using the document class `scrbook`. In the bibliography, there is only one entry where the author is a Tibetan. The bib entry looks like

```
@book{si-tu_min_1990,
  location =     {Sansal},
  title =    {Miṅ daṅ rtags rjes su ston pa’i bstan bcos ’Chi med
                  mdzod kyi rgya cher ’grel ba ’Dod ’jo’i ba mo. In:
                  Collected Works of the Great Tai’i Si tu pa kun
                  mkhyen chos kyi byun (sic) gnas bstan pa’i nyin
                  byed},
  volume =   {vol. 4, pp. 243–738, Vol. 5, pp. 1–422},
  author =   {Si tu Chos kyi ’byuṅ gnas},
  date =     1990,
 }
```

In this case, I want the name to appear as it is in the author field, whereas what I get is Chos kyi ’byuṅ gas, Si tu. How do I get this done?

Comment: It looks like you are abusing the `title` and `volume` fields a bit by including bits of data that should ideally live elsewhere. The entry type might also not be quite right: Maybe it's an `@inbook` instead?

Comment: @moewe, The two volumes I am referring to are, in fact, two volumes. But thanks for pointing out the error. Now the modified entry is: @book{si-tu_min_1990,
  location =  {Sansal},
  title =  {Miṅ daṅ rtags rjes su ston pa’i bstan bcos ’Chi med
                  mdzod kyi rgya cher ’grel ba ’Dod ’jo’i ba mo},
  series = {Collected Works of the Great Tai’i Si tu pa kun
                  mkhyen chos kyi byun (sic) gnas bstan pa’i nyin
                  byed},
  volume =  {4, pp. 243–738, vol. 5, pp. 1–422},
  author =  {{Situ Chos kyi ’byuṅ gnas}},
  date =  1990,
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the author's name in an extra pair of braces? Like in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/using-a-corporate-author-in-the-author-field-of-a-bibliographic-entry-spell).

```
@book{si-tu_min_1990,
  location = {Sansal},
  title = {Miṅ daṅ rtags rjes su ston pa’i bstan bcos ’Chi med mdzod kyi rgya cher ’grel ba ’Dod ’jo’i ba mo. In: Collected Works of the Great Tai’i Si tu pa kun mkhyen chos kyi byun (sic) gnas bstan pa’i nyin byed},
  volume = {vol. 4, pp. 243–738, Vol. 5, pp. 1–422},
  author = {{Si tu Chos kyi ’byuṅ gnas}},
  date = 1990,
}
```

Comment: thanks. It now appears as Si tu Chos kyi ’byuṅ gnas, but it is misplaced. It comes in between Takahata and Uddyotakara.

Comment: Sorts OK with me, using an authortitle style. We will need more information. Are you able to post a small example code which reproduces the problem?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-bibprefixsort) will be of help with the sorting order.

Comment: @Cicada \documentclass[11pt,english]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}

% !BIB program = biber

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=philosophy-modern,
publocformat=loccolonpub,
inbeforejournal=true]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{mybiblio.bib}

\begin{document}

Comment: @LataDeokar (a) make sure you have deleted the temp files bbl if a previous run has produced incorrect output and you have changed code; (b) just to double-check: you have run xelatex biber xelatex?

Comment: @Cicada, yes it worked. I had forgotten to delete the temp bbl file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LataDeokar In general it should not be necessary to delete the `.bbl` file. It is automatically regenerated when you run Biber. It should have been enough to modify the `.bib` file and re-run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). In exceptional circumstances it may be necessary to really delete some temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...), but that is usually only required if you get an error. Not if you just get the wrong sorting.

Comment: @moewe, thanks. I am just a beginner in LaTex, so trying to learn, although bit slowly.

Answer (score 1):

I get STU sort order with the code supplied.

[image: STU sort order]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{x,
  author = {Takahata},
  title  = {xxx},
}
@book{y,
  author = {Uddyotakara},
  title  = {xxx},
}
@book{si-tu_min_1990,
  location = {Sansal},
  title    = {Miṅ daṅ rtags rjes su ston pa’i bstan bcos
              ’Chi med mdzod kyi rgya cher ’grel ba ’Dod ’jo’i ba mo.
              In: Collected Works of the Great Tai’i Si tu pa
              kun mkhyen chos kyi byun (sic) gnas bstan pa’i nyin byed},
  volume   = {vol. 4, pp. 243–738, Vol. 5, pp. 1–422},
  author   = {{Si tu Chos kyi ’byuṅ gnas}},
  date     = 1990,
}
\end{filecontents*}

%===================================================

\documentclass[11pt,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus} 
%
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=philosophy-modern,
  publocformat=loccolonpub,
  inbeforejournal=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\begin{document} 
\cite{y}
\cite{x}

\cite{si-tu_min_1990}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```