# authors name and last names in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I am using `plainnat.bst` in Overleaf to generate the bibliography. But when I compile the name of the author appears first and their last name appears afterward, and it has been ordered automatically by alphabetic of last names!. As an example:

> National Grid Gas.Gas Tranportation, Transmission Planning Code. NationalGrid, 2017. 92
>
> Pratibha Gautam,  Sunil Kumar,  and Snehal Lokhandwala.   Energy-awareintelligence in megacities.  InCurrent Developments in Biotechnology andBioengineering, pages 211–238. Elsevier, 2019. 40
>
> British Petroleum Global.  Bp statistical review of world energy june 2017.Relatório. Disponível:  http://www. bp. com/en/global/corporate/energy-economics/statistical-review-of-world-energy. html, 2017. 15104

As you can see it is ordered by last name priority!

How can I change of priority from last name to first name? Or how can change the code to have last name first appear then name?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: Names of 'corporate authors' such as *National Grid Gas* and *British Petroleum Global* must be given in an additional pair of curly braces to stop them from being split up like a normal name with first and last name. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. You want `author = {{National Grid Gas}},` and `author = {{British Petroleum Global}},`.