# Change citation for alpha bibliographystyle

Tags: citing

I am writing my master thesis and it´s my first time I am using latex. I have some problems changing the citation styles.
Have a look at this citation:

[image: citation1]

and here is the part from my bib file:

```
@misc{JayAlammar.2018,
 author = {{Jay Alammar}},
 year = {2018},
 title = {The Illustrated Transformer},
 url = {http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/},
 urldate = {07.05.2020}
}
```

As you can see the citation takes the first three characters from the authors first name and the year. But what I want is something like this `[JA18]`, so the citation is first letter from firstname, first letter from lastname and the year.

The same problem I have with more then one author:

[image: citation 2]

```
@misc{JeffreyPenningtonRichardSocherChrstiopherD.Manning.2014,
 author = {{Jeffrey Pennington, Richard Socher, Chrstiopher D. Manning}},
 date = {2014},
 title = {GloVe: Global Vectors for Word Representation},
 url = {https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf},
 urldate = {23.05.2020}
}
```

According to [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_citation_styles) on Overleaf the citation should be `[PSM14]`. The first lastname character from all authors and the year.
Btw, I also don´t know why I do not get the year in the citation. In Citavi I picked for the first citation internetdocument and for the second citation report. In both citations I added the year.

And here my thesis_main:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{libertine}
here some other stuff for listings...
\begin{document}
here some other latex files with thesis chapters
\end{document}

\bibliographystyle{alphaurl}
\bibliography{thesis_references}
```

Here is an image how I define my citations in Citavi.
[image: citavi]

Please expain me how to change the citation style to my desires.
Thank you!

Comment: If you use double braces on names BibTeX isn't able to properly separate first and last name. The correct input would be `author = {Jay Alammar},` and `author = {Jeffrey Pennington and Richard Socher and Chrstiopher D. Manning},` (all names separated with `and` regardless of the desired output).

Comment: With BibTeX you will want to give the publication year/date in the `year` field (i.e. `year = {2014},` instead of `date = {2014},`). `date` is only recognised by `biblatex` styles.

Comment: @moewe Thank you for your comment. I added a picture how I defined my citation in Citavi. So I guess the problem why I don´t get what I want is caused by Citavi?

Comment: @moewe you are right. I just manually changed my bib file and now I get the right citation. Thank you so much, I never expected that. If you write this as a solution I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names are incorrectly exported to the `.bib` file. People's names should never be enclosed in additional braces as that will stop BibTeX from correctly separating first and last name. Braces are only necessary for corporate authors precisely in order to stop BibTeX from misparsing corporate names into first and last name parts, see [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864).

So your first entry should be

```
@misc{JayAlammar.2018,
  author  = {Jay Alammar},
  year    = {2018},
  title   = {The Illustrated Transformer},
  url     = {http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/},
  urldate = {07.05.2020}
}
```

For the second entry you additionally need to keep in mind that names must always be separated with `and` regardless of the desired output. Additionally,  most BibTeX styles won't know a `date` field and need the publication year in a `year` field. There also appeared to be a typo in `Chrstiopher`, which should probably be `Christopher`.

```
@misc{JeffreyPenningtonRichardSocherChrstiopherD.Manning.2014,
  author  = {Jeffrey Pennington and Richard Socher and Christopher D. Manning},
  year    = {2014},
  title   = {{GloVe}: Global Vectors for Word Representation},
  url     = {https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf},
  urldate = {23.05.2020}
}
```

---

Citavi should be able to properly export the author names, but you need to input them in a way that allows Citavi to separate them.

Citavi uses semicolons (`;`) and not commas to separate different names. Commas are used to separate name parts. In Citavi the input for author list of the second entry would be

```
Pennington, Jeffrey; Socher, Richard; Manning, Christopher D.
```

[image: name list in Citavi]

You can click on "Autor" for a more sophisticated name input method.

[image: name editor]

---

Note that the style `alphaurl` you use does not know a `urldate` field (which again is a `biblatex` field), but an equivalent `lastchecked` field.