# Small spaces for \textcite name

Tags: biblatex, spacing, citing

I want to have small spaces, i.e `\,`, between the name parts for a citation with `\textcite`. `\renewcommand{\bibinitdelim}{\,}` did not work.

[image: pa]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @book{DINENISO527-1,
        author = {{DIN EN ISO 527-1}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-numeric, citestyle=numeric-comp, sorting=nyt, autocite=inline, isbn=false, innamebeforetitle=true, giveninits=true, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex} \addbibresource{test.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibinitdelim}{\,}

\begin{document}

    \Huge 
    
    DIN\,EN\,ISO\,527-1 \autocite{DINENISO527-1}

    DIN EN ISO 527-1 \autocite{DINENISO527-1}

    \textcite{DINENISO527-1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want small spaces here, you should input small spaces, i.e. say `@book{DINENISO527-1, author = {{DIN\,EN\,ISO\,527-1}},}`. Biber passes the name through as is (because of the braces), so if you have normal spaces, you'll get normal spaces in the `.bbl`.

Comment: @moewe I'm using Zotero and Export it with the BetterBibtex extension, so I can't manually Put in small spaces

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. (I wouldn't know how.) BetterBibTeX can be instructed to do all sorts of shenanigans. The first thing I'd try is using ` ` (U+202F) or ` ` (U+2009) instead of the normal space when you enter the reference in Zotero. Or you can use `<script>DIN\,EN\,ISO\,527-1</script>` (see https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/exporting/advanced/).

Comment: BBT translates U+2009 to `\,`. I don't currently map U+202F -- is U+202F a better mapping for `\,` than U+2009?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `biblatex` punctuation command/delimiter that applies here. Since you (correctly, see [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)) protect the `DIN EN ISO 527-1` with an additional pair of braces to stop it from being parsed as a personal name (and being split into given and family parts), it ends up like this in the `.bbl` file

```
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{hash=f9811a86a7ebf8984f8c4efa2d2d34ec}{%
       family={{DIN EN ISO 527-1}},
       familyi={D\bibinitperiod}}}%
  }
```

So `biblatex` gets to see `DIN EN ISO 527-1` as a single unit with normal spaces. It would be pretty hard to get LaTeX to replace these spaces with thin spaces.

If you want thin spaces I think the best method is to make sure to give small spaces in the `.bib` file. If you are using a reference manager like Zotero to export `.bib` files this may not be as easy as writing

```
author = {{DIN\,EN\,ISO\,527-1}},
```

but it should be possible.

Since you are using BetterBibTeX, I'd try the following (I don't use Zotero or BetterBibTeX, so this is just guesswork based on what I know about the `.bib` export)

- Use other Unicode spaces. For example   (U+202F) or   (U+2009). If you are lucky one of them is exported as `\,` or as something that comes close enough to `\,`.
- Use `<script>DIN\,EN\,ISO\,527-1</script>` to avoid any conversion of special characters (see https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/exporting/advanced/).

If all else fails and you insist on inputting

```
author = {{DIN EN ISO 527-1}},
```

with normal spaces, you can still have Biber remap those spaces. This has to be used carefully though, so you need a flag to tell Biber whether or not to apply the mapping.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-numeric,
  citestyle=numeric-comp,
  sorting=nyt,
  maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=2,
  giveninits=true, 
  autocite=inline,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  isbn=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareEntryOption{smallspaces}{}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=options, match=\regexp{(\A|,)\s*smallspaces\s*(\Z|,)}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{\s}, replace=\regexp{\\,}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{DINENISO527-1,
  author  = {{DIN EN ISO 527-1}},
  options = {smallspaces},
}
@book{DINENISO527-2,
  author  = {{DIN\,EN\,ISO\,527-2}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \Huge 
  
  DIN\,EN\,ISO\,527-1 \autocite{DINENISO527-1}

  DIN EN ISO 527-1 \autocite{DINENISO527-1}

  \textcite{DINENISO527-1}

  \textcite{DINENISO527-2}

  \textcite{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: DIN,EN,ISO,527-1 [1]//DIN EN ISO 527-1 [1]//DIN,EN,ISO,527-1 [1]//DIN,EN,ISO,527-2 [2]//Sigfridsson and Ryde [3]]

It is a matter of style, but I find the version with `\,` too crammed and much harder to read than the version with normal spaces.