# Biblatex: author with two or three word names (not Spanish)

Tags: biblatex

How to make biblatex store, print and sort authors with two or three word names, such as:

> Dionysius Periegetes
>
> Didymus the Blind
>
> Pliny the Elder

The last name perhaps poses no problem in European Portuguese (it is written: Plínio-o-Velho).
But when I insert the name Dionysius Periegetes `biblatex` thinks that Periegetes is a family name, but in fact it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to 'keep a name together' as a complete unit you can enclose it in additional curly braces (just like you would do for 'corporate names': [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)), so here you would say

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{names,
  author    = {{Dionysius Periegetes}
               and {Didymus the Blind}
               and {Pliny the Elder}},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,names}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Dionysius Periegetes, Didymus the Blind and Pliny the Elder (1972). A Theory on Brontosauruses. London: Monthy & Co.]

For many intents and purposes that is probably enough. If you want to shorten the names in citations, you may want to look into using the `shortauthor` field

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{names,
  author      = {{Dionysius Periegetes}
                 and {Didymus the Blind}
                 and {Pliny the Elder}},
  shortauthor = {Dionysius and Didymus and Pliny},
  title       = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year        = {1972},
  publisher   = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location    = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,names}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Dionysius, Didymus and Pliny 1972]