# Citing a Website in Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf, online

This is my input in my references.bib:

```
@ONLINE{alma,
    author = {ALMA Observatory}
    title = {Origins | ALMA}
    date = {2021-03}
    url = {www.almaobservatory.org/en/about-alma/origins}
}
```

My output is ALMA Observatory. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong based on the available information online. Even changing the author to {Observatory, ALMA} doesn't work so I don't think it's about my formatting.

My \bibliographystyle is plain.

The output I'm looking for is something like " “Origins | ALMA.” ALMA, [www.almaobservatory.org/en/about-alma/origins/](http://www.almaobservatory.org/en/about-alma/origins/).  " which is what I get on Easybib. I'm using a template for school (required)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Your question has nothing to do with Overleaf, which is an editing environment. But without seeing how you are producing the bibiliography, it will be difficult to help you. Can you edit your question to show a tiny document that loads just the bibliography package/style you're using. It's also not clear what output you actually want.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "doesn't work"?  Also, have you tried including the "https://"?

Comment: `author = {ALMA Observatory}` should be `author = {{ALMA Observatory}}` with an additional pair of curly braces to stop BibTeX (or Biber) from trying to parse it as the name of a person. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. Maybe that is already enough. If things still don't look right, we will need more details about your document. The output strongly depends on the bibliography packages (`natbib`, `jurabib`, `biblatex`, ...) that you load and the style you use (`\bibliographystyle` or `biblatex`'s `style` option). ...

Comment: ... Please share a short example document that shows how you produce your bibliography with us. (Such a short example document is often called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Comment: Hi all! Thanks for the replies. I've added https:// and the {{ALMA Observatory}} to my citation but neither of those work. I just think having "ALMA Observatory" as a reference doesn't say where I got the information from.

Comment: You've still not clarified what your problem is.  Is your complaint that the reference should have the url in its citation?  Are you using BibTeX, or Biber?  What bibliography style are you using?  Please read through the links that moewe posted, and follow those steps so that we can understand what you're doing and why you think it isn't working.

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{plain}` is one of the basic BibTeX styles written in the late eighties. It does not know a dedicated `@online` type and does not support a `url` field. You could try a more modern style like `\usepackage{natbib}`'s `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`, or you need to put the URL into `howpublished`: `howpublished = {\url{https://www.almaobservatory.org/en/about-alma/origins/}},` and use `@misc` instead of `@online`.

Comment: I'm not really sure how else I can state my issue. I've tried everything suggested in the comments and the only output I get is `"ALMA Observatory"`. Using `@misc` with the `howpublished =` also doesn't work. The way I'm producing my bibliography is with this: `\bibliographystyle{plain}` `\bibliography{References}` where References is my .bib file.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I expect the bibliography to show where my source is from and not just the author. In other words, how can I get the url to show?