# Wrongly print content - biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have using `biblatex` and the below content is wrongly print in PDF. How to tag this bib file. Kindly advise.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel,hyperref,fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes,microtype}
\usepackage[bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric,sorting=none,maxbibnames=5]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ipab730bbib24,
 author ={The National Academies of Sciences Engineering Medicine},
 date={2016},
 editor={Akemann, G \textit{et al}},
 title ={Achieving Science with CubeSats: Thinking Inside the Box},
 location={Washington, DC},
 publisher={The National Academies Press},
 editor={Rao A and others},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

In PDF its printing `Sciences Engineering Medicine The National Academies of` instead of `The National Academies of Sciences Engineering Medicine`. How to code `collab` in `biblatex`?

`editor` is also wrongly print in PDF. It should be `G Akemann et al`. How to achieve this?

Comment: `editor={Akemann, G and others},` and `author ={{The National Academies of Sciences Engineering Medicine}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It's working fine. But i want `et al` should be `italic` format. How to do this?

Comment: you could start by providing a complete example so that one doesn't have to guess your biblatex style.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have modified the questions and kindly advise `et al` should be in `italic` format...

Comment: The question about the national academies is separate from the question about the "et al." For the national academies Ulrike has already given the correct answer and the question is in fact a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. For one bit of the "et al." question Ulrike has also already pointed out the right input, but the correct way to italicise the "et al." depends on your style and language settings. Please ask about only one issue per question in the future. That makes your question easier to answer and more relevant for other people.

Comment: @moewe: In the future i will ask one question at a time only and thanks for your advise. How to modify the `language settings` in the `LaTeX` file instead of modify in the default `english.lbx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) mentioned [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599358/wrongly-print-content-biblatex#comment1502476_599358) and is explained in [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864) you need to protect corporate authors with an additional pair of curly braces. So `author = {The National Academies of Sciences Engineering Medicine},` should be

```
author = {{The National Academies of Sciences Engineering Medicine}},
```

Furthermore, you should never say `et al.` in a name field, you need to use the keywords `and others`. So `editor={Akemann, G \textit{et al}},` should be

```
editor = {Akemann, G. and others},
```

Currently, your `.bib` entry has two `editor` fields. Only the last survives, the other will be ignored.

To format the "et al." in italics you can redefine the bibmacro `name:andothers`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,maxbibnames=5]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \printdelim{andothersdelim}\bibstring[\mkbibemph]{andothers}}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ipab730bbib24,
  author    = {{The National Academies of Sciences Engineering Medicine}},
  date      = {2016},
  editor    = {Akemann, G. and others},
  title     = {Achieving Science with CubeSats: Thinking Inside the Box},
  location  = {Washington, DC},
  publisher = {The National Academies Press},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The National Academies of Sciences Engineering Medicine. Achieving Science with CubeSats: Thinking Inside the Box. Ed. by G. Akemann et al. Washington, DC: The National Academies Press, 2016.]