# Cant print all authors in citation with natbib

Tags: citing, natbib

So for example i have this citation:

```
@article{Plank,
    author  = {Planck Collaboration},
    title   = {Planck 2018 results. VI. Cosmological parameters},
    year    = {2020},
    journal = {Astronomy \& Astrophysics},
}
```

When i try to cite it using

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear}
...
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\citep*{Plank}
```

I will get following:
(Collabaration, 2020)

Not what i wanted:
(Plank Collabaration, 2020)

This issue happens in nearly all my citations and in all of them the citation is not printed correcly while, the bibliography is correct.
Any ideas where does this bug came from?

Comment: The correct input for "corporate" names like this that do not refer to a person is to wrap the name in an additional pair of curly braces. Otherwise BibTeX will try to parse it into family and given name (which makes no sense). Write `author = {{Planck Collaboration}},` in your `.bib` file. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864

Comment: Thank you! That helped.