# Bibtex citation for specific online data

Tags: bibliographies

Does anyone have experience with citing metereologic data from GES DISC?
I would need my citation to look like this:

> Global Modeling and Assimilation Office (GMAO) (2015), MERRA-2 statD_2d_slv_Nx: 2d,Daily,Aggregated Statistics,Single-Level,Assimilation,Single-Level Diagnostics V5.12.4, Greenbelt, MD, USA, Goddard Earth Sciences Data and Information Services Center (GES DISC), Accessed: 10.07.2020, at doi: 10.5067/9SC1VNTWGWV3

I tried something like this:

```
@misc{Merra2,
author = {Global Modeling and Assimilation Office (GMAO), Goddard Earth Sciences Data
and Information Services Center (GES DISC)},
title = {MERRA-2 statD_2d_slv_Nx 2d, Daily, Aggregated Statistics},
volume = {5},
note = {accessed 03.01.19 },
year = {2015},
doi= {10.5067/9SC1VNTWGWV3},
}
```

outcome is something like this:

[image]

Edit: looking at it again, I think the main problems are 
1st: in the title _ is treated as a command for subscripting 
2nd: empty spaces are just ommited and the title is treated as one word 
3rd: Global Modeling and Assimilation Office is abbreviated 
4th: capitol letters are ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've come across a couple of FAQs here

1. In (La)TeX `_` starts a subscript in math mode. If TeX is not in math mode when the `_` is encountered, TeX throws an error and goes into math mode. If you want to print a literal "_", you need to escape it to `\_`.
2. Because LaTeX goes into math mode after the `_`, spaces are ignored (TeX typesets spaces differently in math mode) and you get italic-like text. Again, you don't want the `_` to start a subscript in math mode, so you need `\_`.
3. `author` is a name field, where BibTeX treats input as names of people with first and last names. Some bibliography styles abbreviate first names leading to the output you see. If you have an author that is not a person, you need to wrap it into curly braces. See [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864).
4. Some bibliography styles apply sentence case to title fields and lowercase letters. You can protect words whose case must not be changed with curly braces. [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864).

So your entry might look like this

```
@misc{Merra2,
  author = {{Global Modeling and Assimilation Office (GMAO),
            Goddard Earth Sciences Data and Information Services Center
            (GES DISC)}},
  title = {{MERRA-2} {statD\_2d\_slv\_Nx 2d}, Daily, Aggregated Statistics},
  note  = {accessed 03.01.19},
  year  = {2015},
  doi   = {10.5067/9SC1VNTWGWV3},
}
```