# Write out individual authors in bibliography (BibDesk)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I am using natbib and BibTex for my bibliography. I customised my bibliography design to unsrtdin-abbrv, to implement my citations after the order, they are in the text and abbreviate the authors. Now I have the problem, that sometimes I cite Books, that do not have individual authors named, but are written by commissions and are also abbreviated in the text. I would like them to be written out. Can anybody help me?

This is my skript:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[super, sort&compress]{natbib}       


\begin{document} 

Text

\bibliography{Quellen} 
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin-abbrvt} 

\end{document}
```

This is the citation:

```
@book{EU_Energy,
    author = {European Commission and Directorate--General for Energy},
    date-added = {2022-03-09 11:34:24 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-03-09 11:34:40 +0100},
    doi = {doi/10.2833/75283},
    publisher = {Publications Office},
    title = {EU energy in figures : statistical pocketbook 2020},
    year = {2020},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://doi.org/10.2833/75283}}
```

The output is:

[2] Commission, E. and for Energy, D.-G.: EU energy in figures : statistical pocketbook 2020. Publications Office, 2020. http://dx.doi.org/doi/10.2833/75283.

And I want it written as:

[2] European Commission and Directorate--General for Energy: EU energy in figures : statistical pocketbook 2020. Publications Office, 2020. http://dx.doi.org/doi/10.2833/75283.

But the other citations should still be abbreviated...

Thank you all, for your help!

Comment: Protect it with an extra pair of braces `author = {{European Commission and Directorate--General for Energy}},`.

Comment: Please confirm if the above solves your problem, if it does, this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/105447.

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem! I did not find the other thread

Comment: Glad the problem is solved. ;-)