# Sorting bibliography alphabetically by last name

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, sorting

I would like to cite my references in a document alphabetically by author's last name. I am using BibTek and the `plain` bibliography style.

Here is a MWE using the `plain` bibliography style:

```
\documentclass [12pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{CMR}
\cite{stacks}
\cite{CotComplex}
\cite{CTC}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{testbib}

\end{document}

@book{CMR,
   author = {Jürgen H. Herzog and Bruns Winfried},
   city = {Cambridge{,} UK},
   edition = {1st},
   month = {December},
   publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
   title = {Cohen-Macaulay Rings},
   year = {2009}}

@misc{stacks,
  author       = {The Stacks Project authors},
  title        = {The {S}tacks {P}roject},
  howpublished = {\url{https://stacks.math.columbia.edu}},
  year         = {2023}}

@misc{CTC,
  author = {nLab authors},
  title = {Cotangent complex},
  howpublished = {\url{https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cotangent+complex}},
  version = {21}
}

@article{CotComplex,
  title={The cotangent complex of a morphism},
  volume={128},
  DOI={10.1090/s0002-9947-1967-0209339-1},
  number={1},
  journal={Transactions of the American Mathematical Society},
  author={Stephen Lichtenbaum and Michael Schlessinger},
  year={1967},
  pages={41–70}}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

This mostly works. The only problem is the exceptional entries (the Stacks Project and nLab). The Stacks Project entry seems to get sorted as if the author's last name was "author", while the nLab entry seems to get sorted as if the author's last name was "nLab". Ideally I would like these two citations to appear last. How can I create such exceptions? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Wrap all author names that are not (to be parsed as) people's names (with given/first and family/last name) in additional curly braces: `author = {{The Stacks Project authors}},` and `author = {{nLab authors}},`. (On the other hand `author = {Jürgen H. Herzog and Bruns Winfried},` is perfectly fine and should remain as-is.) See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. If you had used a style that inverts names into "family, given" order, you'd have gotten nonsensical output, like "authors, nLab" from the versions without curly braces.

Comment: @moewe Hm... Bizarrely, this worked like a charm in my MWE, but didn't seem to do anything at all in my actual document.

Comment: Actually, it did alphabetize "The Stacks Project authors" by the character 'T' instead of 'a', but otherwise did nothing.