# How to wrap "sortname" field through biber sourcemapping?

Tags: biblatex

This issue is related to [this other issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690819/how-to-wrap-author-field-through-biber-sourcemapping).

In my custom entrytype I use two alternate fields: `author` (names of persons) and `usera` (names of institutions).

In any pre-existing sorting template (e.g. nty, anyvt, etc.), the `usera` field must be handled as if it were an `author`/`editor` field.

So, without having/wanting to create a custom sorting template, I thought of using the `sortname` field, through sourcemapping.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX program = lualatex
% !BIB program = biber

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@customa{a,
  author = {Smith, John},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {2000},
}
@customa{b,
  usera = {M M},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {3000},
}
@customa{c,
  usera = {A Z},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {1000},
}
@customa{d,
  author = {Doe, Jane},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {4000},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \pertype{customa}
      \step[fieldsource=usera, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=sortname, fieldvalue={\{$1\}}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{usera}%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printdate%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The sourcemapping code should be equivalent to the following .bib file:

```
@customa{a,
  author = {Smith, John},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {2000},
}
@customa{b,
  usera = {M M},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {3000},
  sortname = {{M M}},
}
@customa{c,
  usera = {A Z},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {1000},
  sortname = {{A Z}},
}
@customa{d,
  author = {Doe, Jane},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {4000},
}
```

but the ordering is not as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping the curly braces in a way that retains them for the sourcemap operation can be a bit painful. I found that the following works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \pertype{customa}
      \step[fieldsource=usera, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=sortname, fieldvalue=\regexp{{$1}}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{usera}%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printdate%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@customa{a,
  author = {Smith, John},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {2000},
}
@customa{b,
  usera = {M M},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {3000},
}
@customa{c,
  usera = {A Z},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {1000},
}
@customa{d,
  author = {Doe, Jane},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {4000},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: A Z. Title. 1000. Doe, Jane. Title. 4000. M M. Title. 3000. Smith, John. Title. 2000.]