Problem on names with BibLatex and APA7
I am using APA 7 with BibLaTeX, and when I try to cite a website, such as Scikit Learn, it mistakenly interprets 'Learn' as the last name. However, I want the entire name to appear together as 'Scikit Learn.' I would like the citation to display as 'Scikit Learn, s.f.' instead of 'Learn, s.f.'
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}

Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem\parencite{Scikit-learn_def}.

@online{Scikit-learn_def,
        author = {Scikit Learn},
    title = {Getting Started},
    url = {https://scikit-learn.org/stable/getting_started.html},
        urldate = {2024-10-06}}


Can you help me please?

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a Minimal Working Example including document class and \begin to \end document environment.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864

Add another pair of braces
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}

% Include bibliography entries directly
\begin{filecontents}{asdf.bib}
    @online{Scikit-learn_def,
        author  = {{Scikit Learn}},
        title   = {Getting Started},
        url     = {https://scikit-learn.org/stable/getting_started.html},
        urldate = {2024-10-06}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{asdf.bib}

\begin{document}
    
    Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem\parencite{Scikit-learn_def}.
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}


