Bypass default NameAlias for a given bib entry
I've set the default name alias to family-given, but then for online author entries I've reverted back to given-family, as often times the "author" is not a person. However, when the author is a person, I would like the name alias to be family-given. E.g. in the MWE, I want "Gonz´alez, G.". How can I set this for one or more specific bib entries?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ext-numeric-comp,sorting=none,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2,language=australian,urldate=comp,dateabbrev=false,articlein=false,innamebeforetitle=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xurl}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias[online]{author}{given-family}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@online{c2es,
    author      = "Center for Climate and Energy Solutions",
    year        = "No date",
    title       = "Renewable energy",
    url         = "https://www.c2es.org/content/renewable-energy/",
    note        = "[Accessed 25 June 2021]"
}

@online{eurostat2023,
    author      = "European Commission",
    year        = 2023,
    title       = "Renewable Energy Statistics",
    url         = "https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Renewable_energy_statistics",
    urldate     = "2024-10-24"
}

@online{gonzalez2008,
    author      = "G. Gonz{\'a}lez",
    year        = 2008,
    title       = "Single and Double Plane Pendulum",
    url         = "http://www.phys.lsu.edu/faculty/gonzalez/Teaching/Phys7221/DoublePendulum.pdf",
    urldate     = "2020-05-20"
}

@online{owid2024,
    author      = "Energy Institute",
    year        = 2024,
    title       = "Share of Energy Consumption by Source, World",
    url         = "https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/share-energy-source-sub?country=~OWID_WRL",
    urldate     = "2024-10-24"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}


Wrap the names of "corporate authors" (non-persons) in an additional pair of curly braces. That prevents them from being parsed and broken up like people's names into family and given name part. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. I.e. author = "{Center for Climate and Energy Solutions}", and author = "{European Commission}",

Eh, that's fine, but since they are mostly corporate authors it would be nice if I didn't have to do that!

I guess I could use this method for the gonzalez2008 entry: author = "{Gonz{\'a}lez, G.}"

Yes, you could. It would be wrong from the way data is expected to be input in .bib files and will mean that many styles don't work as advertised, but if you insist on not using the correct input (braces for corporate names, no braces for people's names) this might get you a little closer to what you want. The thing is that Biber and BibTeX simply cannot tell that "European Commission" is something completely different than "Gabriela González". So you need to make this clear in the input. The way BibTeX and Biber expect this to be made clear is braces for the former case.
